# Converting a Spherical Polar vector to Cartesian

Tags: coordinate-transformation

I have the vector:
$$sin2\theta(cos\phi +\frac 1 2sin\phi)\vec r +2cos2\theta(cos\phi+\frac 1 2sin\phi)\vec \theta +2cos\phi(\frac 1 2cos\phi -sin\phi)\vec \phi$$ in spherical polar coordinates which I would like to convert to cartesian. Is there a an easy way I could achieve this in mathematica? I've only just started using mathematica so I've very little experience with the syntax and the functions available so if you could explain in as much detail as possible I'd appreciate it.

Comment: When I put your title in the search bar for the documentation center, the top hit is [Vector Analysis](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/VectorAnalysis.html), the 7th is
[Changing Coordinate Systems](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ChangingCoordinateSystems.html), and the 4th is
[TransformedField](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedField.html).   All of these might be worth a glance if you want to see what can be done with vector fields in Mathematica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
vec = {Sin[2 θ] (Cos[ϕ] + 1/2 Sin[ϕ]), 2 Cos[2 θ] (Cos[ϕ] + 1/2 Sin[ϕ]), 
  2 Cos[ϕ] (1/2 Cos[ϕ] - Sin[ϕ])}

TransformedField["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", vec, {r, θ, ϕ} -> {x, y, z}] // FullSimplify
```

We get a vector with rather long expressions in $x,y,z$.  Look up the help pages for `TransformedField`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for showing me how to define a vector. If I'm being honest I was hoping the result would be a bit nicer but it's good to know how to be able to do it in the future.

Answer (score 4):

With these definitions of the Cartesian representations of the spherical unit vectors $\vec{r}$, $\vec{\theta}$, $\vec{\phi}$,

```
rr = {Sin[θ] Cos[φ], Sin[θ] Sin[φ], Cos[θ]};
θθ = {Cos[θ] Cos[φ], Cos[θ] Sin[φ], -Sin[θ]};
φφ = {-Sin[φ], Cos[φ], 0};
```

we can write your expression in Cartesian coordinates as

```
Sin[2 θ] (Cos[φ] + 1/2 Sin[φ]) rr + 
2 Cos[2 θ] (Cos[φ] + 1/2 Sin[φ]) θθ + 
2 Cos[φ] (1/2 Cos[φ] - Sin[φ]) φφ // FullSimplify

(*    {Cos[φ] (-(Cos[φ] - 2 Sin[φ]) Sin[φ] + Cos[θ]^3 (2 Cos[φ] + Sin[φ])),
       Cos[φ]^3 - 2 Cos[φ]^2 Sin[φ] + Cos[θ]^3 (Sin[φ]^2 + Sin[2 φ]),
       Sin[θ]^3 (2 Cos[φ] + Sin[φ])}                                           *)
```

Finally, to express these terms as functions of $\{x,y,z\}$,

```
Assuming[Element[x | y | z, Reals],
  TrigExpand[%] //. {r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2],
                     θ -> ArcCos[z/r],
                     φ -> ArcTan[x, y]} // FullSimplify]

(*    {(x (-x^3 y Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] + 2 x^2 y^2 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] - x (-2 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] z^3 + y^3 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] + y z^2 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]) + y (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] z^3 + 2 y^3 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] + 2 y z^2 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2])))/((x^2 + y^2) (x^2 + y^2 + z^2))^(3/2),
       (2 x y Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] z^3 + y^2 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] z^3 + x^5 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] - 2 x^4 y Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] + x^3 (y^2 + z^2) Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] - 2 x^2 y (y^2 + z^2) Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2])/((x^2 + y^2) (x^2 + y^2 + z^2))^(3/2),
       ((2 x + y) (x^2 + y^2))/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2)}    *)
```